# OpenCV Error with openni_node.launch

Tags: kinect, opencv, openni, ros-electric, openni-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a Kinect device, ROS Electric, and I installed the openni package with the ubuntu package ros-electric-openni-kinect.
When I execute the launch file openni_camera/openni_node.launch, I get the following error:

```
[ INFO] [1329197063.574824949]: [/kinect/openni_node1] Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1329197063.577073075]: [/kinect/openni_node1] 1. device on bus 001:06 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'B00366702454044B'
[ INFO] [1329197063.589793690]: [/kinect/openni_node1] searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1329197063.715206707]: [/kinect/openni_node1] Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 1:6 with serial number 'B00366702454044B'
[ INFO] [1329197063.822511727]: rgb_frame_id = '/openni_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1329197063.836168835]: depth_frame_id = '/openni_depth_optical_frame' 
OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong () in cvInitMatHeader, file /tmp/buildd/libopencv-2.3.1+svn6514+branch23/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 162
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /tmp/buildd/libopencv-2.3.1+svn6514+branch23/modules/core/src/array.cpp:162: error: (-13)  in function cvInitMatHeader
```

Do you know what would cause this error?

Please let me know if you need some more information on the issue.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27577/opencv-error-with-openni_node.launch/) by [MorganCormier](https://answers.ros.org/users/360/morgancormier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-02-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at this ---  [Image step is wrong () in cvInitMatHeader](http://answers.ros.org/question/12780/opencv-error-image-step-is-wrong-in/)

---

Originally posted by [gpsinghsandhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2834/gpsinghsandhu/) with karma: 231 on 2012-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gpsinghsandhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2834/gpsinghsandhu/) on 2012-07-28**:
If it is little late and u hv already found the answer u should always answer when resolved